# Out of range error in Crystal Report 2008, using Calculated members?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

I have developed a report in Crystal Report 2008 but When I try to run it, it gives the following error.

I used Calculated members in report and the error come when I try to modify a group within my report.

I tried to solve it and have googled but could find any solution.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1) The column `Favorable` is not present in the grid.

2) There is a bug in Crystal Reports (not entirely unheard of).

At least one person [has recently reported this as an issue](https://cw.sdn.sap.com/cw/ideas/2686) when individual rows do not have all of the columns.